# NetBeans shortcut to go to the Folder location in the Windows Explorer

Tags: netbeans

Is there any way to open the folder location in windows explorer from the left side navigation project window in Netbeans? It is exactly what we do in Visual Studio by right clicking on a folder/project and go to "Open Folder in Explorer" option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add a the "Quick Opener" plugin to get that feature. In netbeans from main menu bar select 'Tools' -> plugins -> add -> search for 'quick opener' plugin, then activate it. You should now have a menu items in the right click menu to 'open in file system'... see http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43217/quickopener

Comment: Anything for Netbeans 12 ?

Comment: Installing QuickOpener-1.5.0.nbm manually for NetBeans 12 provides most of the functionality, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

For NetBeans 12 it is not yet in the available plugins list.
Having found via http://blog.carsoncheng.ca/2020/10/quickly-open-source-code-file-location.html, I downloaded QuickOpener-1.5.0.nbm from https://github.com/Chris2011/QuickOpener-NetBeans/releases and installed via Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded (tab) -> Add Plugins...

Clicking on "Open in Terminal", "Open in File Manager", "Copy Path" icons works just fine. "Open shell in..."/"Open filesystem in..." did not work for me, but I didn't use it previously either.